# Checking a zero-based index is less than a one-based count - General programming

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a 0 based index which is checked against a count. The count starts at 1 as they usually do.

The index *value* needs to be less than or equal to the count, so do I take the least resistance route:

```
if(x < _count) // Do Stuff
```

Or the more semantically correct (as in `x` should be aligned with the count, so it's obvious that it needs to be less than or equal to):

```
if((x + 1) <= _count) // Do Stuff
```

I'm just thinking about code maintenance going forwards.

Comment: Clearly the first. Although you should call it `i` and not `x` so it's instantly obvious that it's an index.

Comment: Thank you, I'm assuming the thinking is that it would then be immediately obvious that it's an index against a count?

Comment: Most programmers I know of, if they encountered the second form, would probably decide that you were having an off day and convert it to the first form. One of the good things about 0-based indexing is it *should* end up producing simpler code.

Comment: Count does not start at `1` - it is possible to have `0` items in your collection.

Comment: Very good point @RufusL - to clarify, whilst a 0 count means you have none, a 0 index means you have 1, hence my poor use of language ;) But I do see exactly what you mean, a count of my 0 index give me 1.

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly suggest

```
if(x < _count)
```

It **is** semantically correct actually. Valid zero-based indices should be strictly less than `count`.

> The count starts at 1 as they usually do

I would say that `count` usually starts with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The cardinal rule of code maintainability is that ***the simpler the code, the better***.  So, I would definitely go with the first approach.

Also, another thing to keep in mind is that unless you have a very good reason to do things differently from everyone else out there, it is best not to deviate.  I have never seen anyone doing anything like `if((x + 1) <= _count)` before, and most people would frown at seeing such a thing, because it takes extra mental effort to figure out what on earth you are doing there, and what your reasons might be for doing it. A coffee mug may slip from someone's hand at seeing such a thing.

Comment: Nice! Not to mention the fact that the second approach adds an operation in the condition, eating up a cycle...

Comment: Oh, I would not worry about the clock cycle even if clock cycles were worth worrying for, since any compiler worth the space it occupies on the disk will optimize both statements into the exact same sequence of instructions.